# Java program time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

I am trying to analyze the time complexity of this `while` loop.
The complexity of checking the size is `O(1)`, and polling takes `O(log k)`. We are doing polling `k` times. The overall time complexity of the loop will be `O`(`k log k`). Is my understanding correct?

```
while (FirstQueue.size() > 1) {
    SecondQueue.add(FirstQueue.poll());
}
```

Comment: Based on your description alone, yes `O(k logk)` sounds correct to me.

Comment: Another assumption that goes into this estimate is that `add` takes at most O(log k).

Comment: Thank You! When I take add into consideration the time complexity will be O(k 2log k) and the overall time complexity will be O(k log k) because the 2 is insignificant.

Comment: Sorry, i might misunderstand but Queue.poll() take O(1), so when you poll k time it must be O(K) why O(logk)? All steps take O(1) so we execute it base on the size of queue (N) i think it must be O(N) or O(K)

Comment: Thank you huy! https://gist.github.com/psayre23/c30a821239f4818b0709 according to this site there are different time complexities for poll depending on type of Queue being used. I didnt think of that